# The field shstrndx in ELF header

Tags: file, elf

What the value of the e_shstrndx field in elf mean?

In my file its value is 4. How can I get the section headers names in the file using this constant?

Comment: Use `e_shoff` to find the location of the section headers (`header[0]`). Then use `e_shstrndx` as an index into the section headers.